# How do I embed a youtube channel?

Tags: youtube

How do I embed a youtube channel that will show the latest video from that user?

Say for instance, the latest video on this page: http://www.youtube.com/citizentube

Please don't tell me to go to http://www.youtube.com/custom_player because that page is dead. And please don't reference http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/overview.html unless you have a specific example. I've looked, haven't found anything.

This is crazy frustrating. Apparently there was embed code right on the channel/user page back in 2010. But it is nowhere to be found now.

Thanks,
Peter

Comment: This is something you could try to find the old documentation. Look for Wayback Machine on the web. I'll allow you to see pages from the past. Just a tip, the API probably doesn't work any longer; you could still try it, though.

Comment: Interesting idea. I found one embed, but I couldn't get it to show the most recent video. Hmm. More searching.

Comment: Just found http://www.google.com/support/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=162242 which is close, but not quite. I'm looking for something that will look like a standard video embed, but will show the latest video from a channel instead of a specific video.

Answer (score 1):

I made a script that find the latest videos from any youtube user of your choice. It contains of both html, php and javascript code. What it basically does is it read the rss feed ( http://www.youtube.com/rss/user/citizentube/videos.rss ) from that user and build a list you can click and watch the videos from. The very last video will load as default. You can try it by adding these few lines of javascript into your website:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://lablogic.net/scripts/infotube/webtube.js"></script>

 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> init(470,65,"citizentube",300,220);  </script>
```

or you can go to: [youtube webviewer](http://lablogic.net/index.php#scripts/infotube/web-tube.php) and customize your own. Just type your channelName behind "channel" and hit "Try it". My php script will then generate the short javascript you need. You can also move the channelviewer with your mouse.

Answer (score 0):

The following page documents a 3 step procedure to do this, using Yahoo Pipes:

http://x10hosting.com/forums/tutorials/161362-how-automatically-embed-latest-video-youtube-channel-your-site.html